# PCAP Program in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pcap, winpcap

#### Following are the errors I am facing when trying to execute PCAP program for getting MAC addresses from AirPCap Adapter in visual studio.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: qqq, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/30/2015 2:38:23 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Release\qqq.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  test1.c
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketGetVersion
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketRequest
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketCloseAdapter
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketGetAdapterNames
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketOpenAdapter
1>C:\Users\Sathwik\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\qqq\Release\qqq.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.33
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

#### Please help me in resolving these

#### Following is the Linker Progress

```
1>------ Build started: Project: qqq, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/30/2015 4:31:40 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Release\qqq.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Link:
1>  
1>  Starting pass 1
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:uuid.lib
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES
1>  
1>  Searching libraries
1>      Searching C:\Users\Sathwik\Desktop\AirCap\developers\WinPcap_Devpack\Lib\wpcap.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\ws2_32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>        Found __imp__GetLastError@0
1>          Referenced in test1.obj
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_KERNEL32
1>          Referenced in kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
1>          Referenced in kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found KERNEL32_NULL_THUNK_DATA
1>          Referenced in kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\user32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\AirCap\developers\Airpcap_Devpack\lib\x64\airpcap.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\AirCap\developers\WinPcap_Devpack\Lib\x64\Packet.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\AirCap\developers\WinPcap_Devpack\Lib\x64\wpcap.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\MSVCRT.lib:
1>        Found @__security_check_cookie@4
1>          Referenced in test1.obj
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(secchk.obj)
1>        Found __imp__free
1>          Referenced in test1.obj
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp__malloc
1>          Referenced in test1.obj
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp__scanf_s
1>          Referenced in test1.obj
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp__printf
1>          Referenced in test1.obj
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found _mainCRTStartup
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>        Found ___report_gsfailure
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(secchk.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj)
1>        Found ___security_cookie
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(secchk.obj)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(gs_cookie.obj)
1>        Found __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_MSVCR100
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found ___CxxSetUnhandledExceptionFilter
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(unhandld.obj)
1>        Found __amsg_exit
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp____getmainargs
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __dowildcard
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(wildcard.obj)
1>        Found __newmode
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(_newmode.obj)
1>        Found _atexit
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>        Found __RTC_Terminate
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(_initsect_.obj)
1>        Found __imp___cexit
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp___exit
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __XcptFilter
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp__exit
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp____initenv
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __IsNonwritableInCurrentImage
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(pesect.obj)
1>        Found __initterm
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found ___xc_a
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>  Processed /DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib
1>   Processed /DISALLOWLIB:libcmt.lib
1>   Processed /DISALLOWLIB:libcmtd.lib
1>   Processed /DISALLOWLIB:msvcrtd.lib
1>        Found __initterm_e
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found ___native_startup_state
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(natstart.obj)
1>        Found __SEH_epilog4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(sehprolg4.obj)
1>        Found __except_handler4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(pesect.obj)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(sehprolg4.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj)
1>        Found __imp___configthreadlocale
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found ___globallocalestatus
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(xthdloc.obj)
1>        Found __setdefaultprecision
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(fp8.obj)
1>        Found __imp____setusermatherr
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __matherr
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(merr.obj)
1>        Found __setargv
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(dllargv.obj)
1>        Found __commode
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(xncommod.obj)
1>        Found __imp___commode
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp___fmode
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __fmode
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(xtxtmode.obj)
1>        Found __imp____set_app_type
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found ___security_init_cookie
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj)
1>        Found __crt_debugger_hook
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found MSVCR100_NULL_THUNK_DATA
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(unhandld.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __unlock
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found ___dllonexit
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __lock
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __imp___onexit
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __except_handler4_common
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __invoke_watson
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(fp8.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>        Found __controlfp_s
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(fp8.obj)
1>          Loaded MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Users\Sathwik\Desktop\AirCap\developers\WinPcap_Devpack\Lib\wpcap.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\ws2_32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>        Found __imp__InterlockedExchange@8
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__Sleep@4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__InterlockedCompareExchange@12
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__HeapSetInformation@16
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__EncodePointer@4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__TerminateProcess@8
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__GetCurrentProcess@0
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__UnhandledExceptionFilter@4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj)
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(unhandld.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__IsDebuggerPresent@0
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__DecodePointer@4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(atonexit.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__QueryPerformanceCounter@4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__GetTickCount@0
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__GetCurrentThreadId@0
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__GetCurrentProcessId@0
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>        Found __imp__GetSystemTimeAsFileTime@4
1>          Referenced in MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj)
1>          Loaded kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\user32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\AirCap\developers\Airpcap_Devpack\lib\x64\airpcap.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\AirCap\developers\WinPcap_Devpack\Lib\x64\Packet.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\AirCap\developers\WinPcap_Devpack\Lib\x64\wpcap.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\MSVCRT.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Users\Sathwik\Desktop\AirCap\developers\WinPcap_Devpack\Lib\wpcap.lib:
1>      Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\ws2_32.lib:
1>  
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>  
1>  Finished pass 1
1>  
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketGetVersion
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketRequest
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketCloseAdapter
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketGetAdapterNames
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PacketOpenAdapter
1>C:\Users\Sathwik\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\qqq\Release\qqq.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.10
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image]

#### NEW Errors

```
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Sathwik\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\qqq\Release\qqq.exe', Symbols loaded.
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Packet.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\airpcap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'qqq.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x23f0) has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[3532] qqq.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These symbols are part of the winPcap library. You need to link your program with `wpcap.lib`. Note that, if you are creating a x86 program, you must link with the x86 library, same goes for x64.

You will also need to ensure the DLL is deployed with your application.

http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcapsamps.html

Comment: @MuertoExcobito.I included all those that were mentioned in the above link. I am updating the image which shows that i added those points. Please help me If I miss any. thanks

Comment: In your compilation output , you are compiling Win32, aka x86, but the library directory you are using is x64. Updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: Changed it to ""\developers\WinPcap_Devpack\Lib"" . But still resulting the same errors

Comment: Try turning on the 'show progress' linker setting. It will show you where the linker is searching for each library, then locate wpcap.lib, and it should be reasonably clear what the issue is.

Comment: I am a begineer in both VS and Winpcap. Updating the status. Can We infer anything from that

Comment: Yes, your wpcap.lib is still being  found in the x64 directory. Make sure you are editing the properties of the correct configuration and platform.

Comment: Those things vanished when i changed it to x86. But when running I am getting option to choose the adapter, but after choosing, the source getting stripped of. Updated them